# How to sync a large CSV file with Django model

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql

I want to process item report every hour for multiple accounts in my system. There are around 150k+ records in each csv. I want to sync report with database in the following way.

1. Create record if it does not exists
2. Update if it is present
3. I want to do this in bulk (in one database query)

Currently I am doing get or create for each record.

I am using Postgres=13.2, Django=3.2.5 and python=3.9

Comment: i think [update or create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) would be more fitting in this situation or take a look at this [package](https://github.com/fopina/django-bulk-update-or-create/) to see how they do it

Comment: update or create is for one record. I need to update or create in bulk for all rows

Comment: Are the csv already in the same structure as the PostgreSQL table, or do they have to go through Django's model to be transformed?

Comment: The only way I see this happening is to create a staging table to load the records into in bulk. Then run something like: `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM table WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM other_table)` and a similar `UPDATE ...` for ids that match. Then `TRUNCATE` staging table.

Comment: @jjanes Thanks Jjanes. Csv is in different format I need to pre process that first.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver. Do you think it is an effective solution to that?

Comment: Well it is a common solution. Effective depends on your particular situation and only some testing can determine that.